# How to attach documents to list items SharePoint 2013 - Microsoft.SharePoint.Client (Error System.IO.FileNotFoundException)

Tags: client-object-model, custom-list, attachments

I have a custom list and i'm using the below.But getting error:

> Could not find file 'c:\windows\system32\inetsrv/Filename -System.IO.FileNotFoundException

```
 if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
        {
            var attachment = new AttachmentCreationInformation();
            //attachment.FileName = @"C:\Others\Exmec\" + FileUpload1.FileName;
            attachment.FileName = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;


            attachment.ContentStream = new MemoryStream(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName));
            Attachment att = oListItem.AttachmentFiles.Add(attachment);
            ctx.Load(att);
        }
```

Any ideas what i'm doing wrong?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Is any of the answer helps you?

Answer (score 0):

Below code is working fine for me. Yours is same except I see execute query command to be missing. Also check if the location specified in the error is accessible and correct parameters are being passed in FileName and ReadAllBytes().

```
 var attInfo = new AttachmentCreationInformation();
attInfo.FileName = mFile.Name;
attInfo.ContentStream = new MemoryStream(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("streamFile"));

Attachment att = item.AttachmentFiles.Add(attInfo); //Add to File

context.Load(att);
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: SHould you not close the stream as well?

Comment: Not required... The issue is the location issue..If user points it to other destination the code will work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I do have the ExecuteQuery() in my code just didn't include it. What needs to happen is when a user is using the form he/she should be able to browse the file from any drive or location to upload.
Why is it trying to find the files in c:\windows\system  etc...

Answer (score 0):

```
using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext("http://SharepointURL/"))
{
    try
    {


        Web web = context.Web;

        FileCreationInformation newFile = new FileCreationInformation();
        newFile.Content = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\test.txt");
        newFile.Url = "test.txt";

        List docs = web.Lists.GetByTitle("CustomList");
    ListItem item = docs.GetItemById(ID);

    var attInfo = new AttachmentCreationInformation();
    attInfo.FileName = mFile.Name;
    attInfo.ContentStream = new MemoryStream(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("streamFile"));

    Attachment att = item.AttachmentFiles.Add(attInfo); //Add to File

    context.Load(att);
    context.ExecuteQuery();
    Console.WriteLine("done");


    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

**Hope this code helps you to attach file to list item.**

If you find any problem in it than please let me know.

Comment: Thanks guys what i found that is that my code works in IE but not in firefox.
When i use firefox i can't seem to get the full path of the file and that's why its failing.
Any suggestions or workarounds?

Comment: You should use **Server.MapPath(FileUpload1.FileName);** to get the file path from where is it going to get the file...

Comment: Thanks Hardik . The server MapPath did work in Firefox but not in IE .. :)

Comment: Sorry this is the snippet I'm using:

            attachment.FileName = Server.MapPath(FileUpload1.FileName);

          
            attachment.ContentStream = new MemoryStream(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Server.MapPath(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName)));

Comment: In IE i get "is a physical path, but a virtual path was expected. "

Comment: have you tried my method ...mentioned in above code?

Comment: Hardik not sure what you mean.I can't map the file to a specific folder or file as they should be able to choose a file from any storage or drive